# Двойной пробел, номер символа в строке

Tags: bash

Нужно отследить позицию двойного пробела, чтобы по нему, как по маркеру, разделить строку на две.

```
str="Происзвольная строка 1.  Продолжение строки и так далее"; 
poz=`expr index "$c" "  " ` ;
echo $poz; 
str1=${c:0:poz}; 
echo $str1;  
str2=${c:poz}; 
echo $str2;
```

Выдаёт ноль и две пустые строки.

Answer (score 4):

можно воспользоваться «родными» средствами программы *bash* по удалению префиксов и суффиксов:

```
str="Произвольная строка 1.  Продолжение строки и так далее"
echo ${str%%  *}
echo ${str##*  }
```

результат:

```
Произвольная строка 1.
Продолжение строки и так далее
```

Comment: но если нужна именно позиция, то [см. здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5032641/4827341)

Comment: `${var%%...}`, `${var##...}` (жадные и нежадные варианты) -- это варианты чистого shell. bash тут не при чём. Читайте http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html

Comment: Спасибо. То что надо.

Comment: @Илья, так пометьте как правильный.